# Why is the 'this' not able to resolve within the service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using ES6 with Babble for constructing an angular app using angular1.x. There is a variable in the controller which is not resolved when I call a Service using Ajax.

**Controller**

```
    export default class MenuController {
    constructor(MenuService) {
        this.Items=[];
        this.MenuService = MenuService;
    }

    getMenu() {
        this.MenuService.getMenuItems().then(function(data) {
            this.Items = data
        });
        console.log(this.Items)
    }
}

MenuController.$inject = ['MenuService'];
```

**Service**

```
    class MenuService {
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    getMenuItems() {
        var promise = null;
        if (!promise) {
            promise = this.$http.get('./data/menu-config.json').then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
        return promise;
    }
}

    MenuService.$inject = ['$http'];

    export default angular.module('services.menu-service', [])
        .service('MenuService', MenuService)
        .name;
```

Now whenever this code is executed I get the following error on the browser console.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'Items' of undefined
    at eval (menu.ctrl.js:23)
    at processQueue (angular.js:14792)
    at eval (angular.js:14808)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15870)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1972)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:2035)
    at done (angular.js:10589)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10787)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12520(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9292processQueue @ angular.js:14800(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14808Scope.$eval @ angular.js:16052Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15870scopePrototype.$digest @ hint.js:1972Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16160scopePrototype.$apply @ hint.js:2035done @ angular.js:10589completeRequest @ angular.js:10787requestLoaded @ angular.js:10728
```

I am not able to rectify this. Whereas I know that there is some referential error. Please help

Comment: use arrow function [`() => {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of `function`

Comment: I dont think that is the problem because Bable is backward compatible and the script generated is pretty fine!

Comment: @Hacketo is arrow function work for all browser?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I guess babel will do the job, it's es6. I linked mdn doc you can see browsers support

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh arrow function let you to use `this`

Comment: `.name;` is doing in your service

Comment: @Hacketo arrow function won't help in this case. The problem is in worng context.

Comment: @Hacketo  Yes you are so correct. it works, this is the generated 
` var _this = this;

            var that = this;
            this.MenuService.getMenuItems().then(function (data) {
                return _this.Items = data;
            });` 
is what is generates, same as @pixelbits mentioned!!! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` depends on the function context.

Save `this` in `that`:

```
 var that = this;
 this.MenuService.getMenuItems().then(function(data) {
        that.Items = data
 });
```

As mentioned in comments, you can use arrow syntax instead:

```
 this.MenuService.getMenuItems().then(data=>this.Items = data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get that Bable generates this out. You got the correct one.